# ConTeXt (mkiv) bibliography not respecting \setupinterlinespace[big]

Tags: bibliographies, context, line-spacing

Early in my document I have `\setupinterlinespace[big]` for double-spacing per course requirements. However, when I do `\placepublications[criterium=all]`, it doesn't seem to respect this. In other words, the works cited list seems to be single-spaced, and putting another instance of `\setupinterlinespace[big]` directly before or after doesn't seem to help. I suspect this is just not a supported feature of this module, but I'd really like to know how I can “trick it” into working, if that's possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\setuplist[pubs]` for the publication list setup in combination with the
`after` hook.

```
\setupbibtex
  [database=sample]

\setuplist
  [pubs]
  [after={\blank[line]}]

\starttext
  \cite[hh2010a, Eijkhout1991]
  \placepublications [criterium=all]
\stoptext
```

The `\blank` is triggered for every entry in the bibliography.